# Assertions fail when inlcuding login and logout in the playback recording

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have added assertions for fields in User Creation Page.
These assertions fail (even though the validations are working fine) when I include login and logout actions in the playback.
If I check the same assertions with only the User creation pages in the playback, they result in PASS.
I am confused about this. Would be glad if I get some info about this.

Comment: Need more information: what kind of exception do you get when the test fails?

Comment: Even the simple field level validations like checking the field captions fail. For instance, i have added validation to check if the header field caption in User Creation page is 'User Management'. This is displayed properly. But the test fails and this is wat i get in the result:
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<User Management>. Actual:<(null)>.

Similary all the field captions are taken as Null, even though they are displayed properly. The same happens for all other validations too. It is taking it all as Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you examine the controls do they have any session token in the properties? If you look through all the window titles and properties and strip out any differing data to make them more generic it would allow coded ui to find the control each time.

Comment: I suspect you have two versions of the controls etc on the screen, although some may be invisible or not displayed. Try using the `DrawHighlight()` method on the UI Controls accessed in the asserts. Also try looking at the `BoundingRectangle`, `Top` and `Left` properties of those controls, perhaps in the debugger.